# new grammar or typo?

Tags: java, junit

here, https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Assertions, look at:

```
public void testAssertThatHamcrestCoreMatchers() {
    assertThat("good", allOf(equalTo("good"), startsWith("good")));
    assertThat("good", not(allOf(equalTo("bad"), equalTo("good"))));
    assertThat("good", anyOf(equalTo("bad"), equalTo("good")));
    assertThat(7, not(CombinableMatcher.<Integer> either(equalTo(3)).or(equalTo(4))));
    assertThat(new Object(), not(sameInstance(new Object())));
}
```

in the 5th line, `CombinableMatcher.<Integer>` is valid? i try it with java6, failed.
is it a new grammar or simple typo?

Comment: *"i try it with java6, failed"* - can you be more specific about what exactly failed?

Comment: Legal syntax, and not at all new. It specifies the `either` method's type parameter.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    java.util.ArrayList<Box<Integer>> listOfIntegerBoxes =
      new java.util.ArrayList<>();
    BoxDemo.<Integer>addBox(Integer.valueOf(10), listOfIntegerBoxes);
    BoxDemo.addBox(Integer.valueOf(20), listOfIntegerBoxes);
    BoxDemo.addBox(Integer.valueOf(30), listOfIntegerBoxes);
    BoxDemo.outputBoxes(listOfIntegerBoxes);
  }
```

> The generic method addBox defines one type parameter named U. Generally, a Java compiler can infer the type parameters of a generic method call. Consequently, in most cases, you do not have to specify them. For example, to invoke the generic method addBox, you can specify the type parameter as follows:

```
BoxDemo.<Integer>addBox(Integer.valueOf(10), listOfIntegerBoxes);
```

Source: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html

Comment: sorry, i have not read generic docs carefully, and the error too. 

the error say: The method either(Matcher<Integer>) is undefined for the type CombinableMatcher.

CombinableMatcher have not that method indeed. maybe is a issue about version.